# Kotlin -How to call finish() in a RecyclerViewAdapter using Binding (not context)

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-viewbinding, activity-finish

I need to finish() the Activity that the RecyclerView is in when an item/row is tapped.

I looked this up but most of the answers referred to the old way of doing things when using `context` and `(context as MyActivity).finish()`. How can I do the same thing using `binding`

```
class MyAdapter(var users: List<User>): RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.UserViewHolder>() {

    inner class UserViewHolder(private val binding: UserRowBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        init {
            binding.root.setOnClickListener {

                val intent = Intent(binding.root.context, NextActivity::class.java)
                binding.root.context.startActivity(intent)

                // call finish() here
            }
        }
    }
}

class MyActivity: App: AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        // ...

        val adapter = MyAdapter(some_array_Of_users)
        binding.recyclerView.adapter = adapter
    }
}
```

Comment: `(binding.root.context as Activity).finish()` should work :P

Comment: IMO it is poor encapsulation for the adapter to be handling this. It should just expose an interface for the Activity to implement and handle the click.

Comment: @Tenfour04 why is this poor encapsulation? Google wants us to use view binding. Are you suggesting with Adapters don't use view binding and instead stick to findViewById? 1 alternative is to just pass the Activity's context to the Adapter and just call it directly. 1) I was trying to avoid that. 2) I'm new to Kotlin. I played around with it before but now I'm taking it seriously but I'm still learning.

Comment: View binding in an adapter is A-OK. I’m talking about making the adapter responsible for navigating between activities. Now the task of navigation is intermingled across two layers. The casting to Activity is one of the smells related to this. It’s just my opinion, take with a grain of salt. Others may disagree. Christian’s answer below is how I would handle it.

Comment: @Tenfour04 thanks for the answer! I'm learning from videos so it'll be a while before I get the hang of it. I'll try is answer tomorrow evening. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also create a listener function on the activity itself.

In Adapter, you can add a variable for your listener. (or you can just add this as parameter of Adapter)

```
val listener: (()->Unit)? = null
```

In ViewHolder, add listener as your parameter and invoke it in setOnClickListener, it should look like this:

```
  inner class UserViewHolder(private val binding: UserRowBinding, private val listener: (()->Unit)? = null): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

    init {
        binding.root.setOnClickListener {
            listener?.invoke()
        }
    }
}
```

In your Activity, you can just set the variable listener value. In that case, you can set the 'finish()' that you are looking for. Something look like this,

```
class MyActivity: App: AppCompatActivity() {

lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    // ...

    val adapter = MyAdapter(some_array_Of_users)
    adapter.listener = { moveToOtherActivity() }
    this.adapter = adapter
}

  private fun moveToOtherActivity() {
      val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, NextActivity::class.java)
      startActivity(intent)
      finish()
    }
}
```

or just add a parameter in your adapter,

```
class MyAdapter(var users: List<User>, val listener: (()->Unit?=null): RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.UserViewHolder>()
```

And in Activity,

```
 val adapter = MyAdapter(some_array_Of_users, {moveToOtherActivity()})
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I'm just getting into Kotlin and I'm learning from YT videos. I'll study your answer tomorrow evening to see if I can comprehend it. If I try it and it works I'll accept your answer and give you the upvote for extra points. Cheers!!!

Comment: checked it out and it works. Thanks! I did both upvotes as I promised :)

Comment: I forgot to mention in iOS this is called a closure, or more specifically an `Optional Closure`. It's the same exact concept except instead of `Unit`, `Void` is used. Like this `var listener: (()->Void)?`

Answer (score 0):

`finish()` is the method of the `Activity` class. So your task can be rephrased as

> How I can get the reference on the `Activity` from my `Adapter`?

So you have at least 2 options:

1. Use your `itemView` to get the `Context`:

   ```
   (itemView.context as Activity).finish()
   ```
2. Get the `Context` from binding:

   ```
   (binding.root.context as Activity).finish()
   ```

**Small advice:**

Also you can consider to delegate click handling to the caller side and pass it to the adapter. It may be more correct in terms of architecture. And there will not be a problem to find the reference to your `Activity`. Something like this:

```
class MyAdapter(var users: List<User>, private val onClick: OnClickListener): RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.UserViewHolder>() {

    inner class UserViewHolder(private val binding: UserRowBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        init {
            binding.root.setOnClickListener {
                onClick()
            }
        }
    }
}

class MyActivity: App: AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        // ...

        val adapter = MyAdapter(some_array_Of_users) {                     
            val intent = Intent(binding.root.context, NextActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            this@MainActivity.finish()
        }
        binding.recyclerView.adapter = adapter
    }
}
```